# Spring-integration / ActiveMQ subscribe to multiple destinations in a single thread

Tags: multithreading, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I am using multiple `<si:service-activator>`'s and `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`'s to subscribe to multiple queues and topics. Messages from each destination are received in a separate thread, which means that my receiving code is full of locks to guard the mutable internal state.

I would like my receiving code to be lock free. Is it possible to configure spring-integration/activemq to receive from multiple destinations on the same thread?

If this is not possible, I can think of two alternatives:

1. Start my own processing thread which reads from a blocking queue, put all received messages on this queue.
2. Dispatch all received messages onto a single destination and consume from this.

Anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [wildcard pattern](https://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html) on a single queue.

That is, instead of reading from two queues, use one queue and specify all queues you want to read from in the name.

that is: `"QUEUE.NR1,QUEUE.NR2"` or `"SOME.PREFIX.>"` to read all queues with that prefix. Your client code handle this as a single queue.

Comment: Yes this does work.  Note: queues subscribed to via wildcards (even 2 comma seperated) are not shown in the web console until the first message is received.  The next problem is how to mix queues and topics with wildcards?

Comment: Use VirtualTopics to use queues to subscribe to topics. You cannot really mix otherwise. http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html